# end a running lua script

Tags: mfc, lua

I have a MFC dialog based app and have integrated Lua. The dialog has a text editor component so that the user can input a script. The dialog also has a button 'Run' which when pressed does:    luaL_loadstring( luaVM,theScript); lua_pcall(luaVM,0,0,0); where luaVM is my main lua_State* . The dialog also has another button 'Stop' and I want when pressed to be able to stop the currently running script started by 'Run', but I cannot come up with an approach. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know about MFC but if MFC allows you to handle one GUI event by hand, then you can set a count hook to do that every so often.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing a Lua script to exit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913999/forcing-a-lua-script-to-exit)

Answer (score 1):

Lua is not intended to be used in such a fashion. Lua is inherently single-threaded (hardware CPU threads, not Lua threads). Once a script starts, there is no way to simply terminate it, unless you *design* that script to be able to terminate.

What you would have to do is start the user's script as a coroutine. And that coroutine would have to frequently (and *manually*) yield, so that you could check to see if you should stop the script. Since this is a manual process, you would either need the user to properly instrument their code or you would need to modify their script and add `yield` calls appropriately.

You might be able to use some debug hook to check every few seconds and yield the coroutine if you need it to stop. However, I have no idea if this would actually work, if it is legal to yield from a debug hook.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a debug hook that sleeps for a bit.

See http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_sethook