# Interrupt a call to zmqpp::poller::poll() from another thread

Tags: c++, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I'm using the [zmqpp](https://github.com/zeromq/zmqpp) C++ binding of [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) for building a PUB/SUB communication.

On the subscriber side, there are 2 threads -- `mainThread` and `pollingThread`.

`pollingThread` contains a blocking call to [`zmqpp::poller::poll(zmqpp::poller::wait_forever)`](https://zeromq.github.io/zmqpp/classzmqpp_1_1poller.html#a01b41636a7851d0e1ddfdcfdf15d635b).

**How, from wihin `mainThread`, can I interrupt/cancel `pollingThread`'s call to `poll()` ?**

EDIT1: I'm using `std::thread`, so [I can't interrupt the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13893149/865719).

EDIT2: Here's basically `pollingThread`'s function.

```cpp
void pollingThread()
{
    while (threadCanRun())
    {
        // wait indefinitely for a new message
        if (mySocketPoller->poll())
        {
            functionToCallWhenAMessageArrives();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you chose `zmqpp::poller::wait_forever`?

Comment: Yes. I want to call a particular function only when a new message is broadcast by the publisher. Please check out the edited post for the basic code of `pollingThread`.

Answer (score 2):

The recommend way would, IMO, be to rely on message passing to handle this.

That would mean:

1. create a pair of INPROC PAIR socket. One per thread. Connect them.
2. on the polling thread, also `poll()` on your PAIR socket.
3. when you want to interrupt the polling thread, send a message from your PAIR socket to the PAIR socket of the polling thread.
4. The call to `poll()` will then return.

Note that this solution, while recommended, will require you to change bits of your code.

```
    if (mySocketPoller->poll())
    {
        if (mySocketPoller->has_input(my_pair_socket))
        {
         // interrupted.
        }
        functionToCallWhenAMessageArrives();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.