# std alternative to boost::this_thread_interruption_point

Tags: c++, boost, std

I am working on a C++ project that uses boost 1.61, I am replacing boost with std calls, is there an alternative to boost::this_thread::interruption_point() ?

Comment: Have you looked at `std::jthread` and stop tokens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::thread` is not interruptable. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893060/i-want-to-kill-a-stdthread-using-its-thread-object). However there is [std::jthread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) in C++-20, that you can try to use. Unfortunately, according to [compiler-support list on cpp-reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), only libstdc++ 10+ supports `std::jthread`.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't an option I can use as I'm limited to version of C++ available.  The development environment is VS2013.

Comment: @SPlatten, then you can either not rewrite work with thread on std, or you can attempt to use native handle and interrupt it, if there is no need in cross-platforming.

Comment: I just opened the thread C++11 header, it does not contain jthread.

Comment: I'll give you the tick, because I don't think there is a correct answer to my particular problem but you have been very helpful.

Comment: A more correct answer is to use the approach to implement it yourself like in CCiA https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action-second-edition